# Non-latin-characters ordering in database with "order by"

Tags: sql, database, string, comparison, sql-order-by

I just found some strange behavior of database's "order by" clause. In string comparison, I expected some characters such as '[' and '_' are greater than latin characters/digits such as 'I' or '2' considering their orders in the ASCII table. However, the sorting results from database's "order by" clause is different with my expectation. Here's my test:

<strike>SQLite version 3.6.23

    Enter ".help" for instructions

    Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"

    sqlite> create table products(name varchar(10));

    sqlite> insert into products values('ipod');

    sqlite> insert into products values('iphone');

    sqlite> insert into products values('[apple]');

    sqlite> insert into products values('_ipad');

    sqlite> select * from products order by name asc;

    [apple]

    _ipad

    iphone

    ipod</strike>

```
select * from products order by name asc;
name
...
[B@
_ref
123
1ab
...
```

This behavior is different from Java's string comparison (which cost me some time to find this issue). I can verify this in <strike>both SQLite 3.6.23 and</strike> Microsoft SQL Server 2005. I did some web search but cannot find any related documentation. Could someone shed me some light on it? Is it a SQL standard? Where can I find some information about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Huh? That is exactly what how Java sorts for me, too. What kind of java do you have that sorts _ behind i?

Comment: Sorry, I want to simplify my issue so that others can reproduce it easily but I am too hurried and the sqlite3 example is incorrect. I can only find this issue in SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of comparing and ordering the characters in a database is called **collation**.

How the strings are stored depends on the collation which is usually set in the server, client or session properties.

In `MySQL`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  'a' AS str
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'A' AS str
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'b' AS str
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'B' AS str
        ) q
ORDER BY
        str COLLATE UTF8_BIN


--
'A'
'B'
'a'
'b'
```

and

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  'a' AS str
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'A' AS str
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'b' AS str
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'B' AS str
        ) q
ORDER BY
        str COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI


--
'a'
'A'
'b'
'B'
```

`UTF8_BIN` sorts characters according to their unicode. Caps have lower unicodes and therefore go first.

`UTF8_GENERAL_CI` sorts characters according to their alphabetical position, disregarding case.

Collation is also important for indexes, since the indexes rely heavily on sorting and comparison rules.

Answer (score 1):

The important keyword in this case is ['collation'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation). I have no experience with SQLite, but would expect it to be similar to other database engines in that you can define the collation to use for whole databases, single tables, per connection, etc.

Check your DB documentation for the options available to you.

Comment: SQLite uses binary collation by default (forgot to specify that my answer was about SQLite).

Answer (score 0):

The ASCII codes for lower-case characters such as 'i' are greater than the ones for '[' and '_':

```
'i': 105
'[': 91
'_': 95
```

However, try to insert upper-case characters, eg. try with "IPOD" or "Iphone", those will become before "_" and "[" with the default binary collation.